navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value) not work in mobile
I wrote a code to get param from php get method and copy it to clipboard in laptop and pc work fine, but I try many phones and it doesn't work, notice that if I use a btn to click on it's work but in case of auto call    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value)
it does not work! my code is :


function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  alert("copied pin is: " + copyText.value);
}

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction()
  }, 500);
  myFunction();
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.close();
  }, 100);
};
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['pin'];?>" id="myInput">




I think it's common that functions that manipulate the clipboard have to be triggered from a user interface element. I'm more surprised that it works on the desktop.

window.close(); won't work. Only the script that opened a window can close it.

I tried your code on a desktop and it didn't work.

@Barmar , ok do you have solution ?

No. I think this is by design, for security reasons. All web applications that update the clipboard require you to click on something first.
